# Where can I put a customised class file to avoid copying it in every file folder?

Tags: miktex, documentclass-writing

I have written a class file to give my papers a customised style. The thing is... I have several file folders with several different papers in each one. If I want to apply the style of the class file to these papers, the way I'm doing things now, I have to paste the .cls file in every folder. Is it possible to place the .cls file in one folder, together with the others classes?

I'm using MikTex 2.9 on windows.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you don't like the default MikTeX file location, you can go into the MikTeX maintenance options menu, under "Roots" and define a new directory to place files.  Clicking, in that menu, the "Show MikTeX maintained root directories" will give an answer to your question.  Below the root (so-called localtexmf) directory, the subdirectory to place `cls` and `sty` files should be `tex\latex\...`

Answer (score 2):

You will get an answer to your question 
[here](https://docs.miktex.org/faq/maintenance.html#styfiles) in MikTeX's FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

You can place in the below folder:

```
C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\local
```

Comment: As always, you will need to go to Start -> All Programs -> MiKTeX 2.9 -> Maintenance (Admin) -> Settings (Admin).  Under the General tab, click both Refresh FNDB and Update Formats.  It is recommended that you should click them each twice (so click Refresh FNDB, Update Formats, Refresh FNDB, and Update Formats) just to be sure.  Otherwise, MiKTeX might not find the new class and BST files.

Comment: In Unix, local trees (like `$HOME/texmf/...`) are searched every time, not cached, so there is no need to refresh the file DB. Isn't the same in Windows?